# Node JS - Pass parameter into multiple API requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have started to learn nodeJS and I have created a little stock web app where you can search up a stock ticker (for example, 'TSLA') and it would return stock information such as the price, stock exchange, change in price etc. I wanted to take it one step further and be able to obtain any news regarding that specific stock. The issue I am having right now is that it is currently unable to grab and display the news. However, if I remove the request API to obtain the stock information, the news would be displayed. I appreciate the help if possible.

```
// Request API to obtain stock information
function call_api(finishedAPI, ticker){
  request(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${ticker}/quote?token=`, {json: true}, (err, res, body) =>{
  if (err){ 
    console.log(err)}
  if (res.statusCode === 200){
    // console.log(body)
    finishedAPI(body)
  };
});
};

// Request API to obtain stock news
function news_API(newsAPI, test){
  request(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${test}&apiKey=`, {json: true}, (err, res, body) =>{
  if (err){ 
    console.log(err)}
  if (res.statusCode === 200){
    console.log(body.articles[0].author)
    newsAPI(body)
  };
});
};


// Stock page
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
  call_api(function(doneAPI){
    res.render('index',{ title: 'Stock',
      stock: doneAPI
    });
  }, 'TSLA');
});

//POST data for stock submitting.
app.post('/', (req,res) =>{
  call_api(function(doneAPI){
    res.render('index',{ title: 'Stock',
      stock: doneAPI
    });
  }, req.body.stockText);
});


//News 
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
  news_API(function(newsAPI){
    res.render('index',{ title: 'Stock',
      stock: newsAPI
    });
  }, 'TSLA');
});

app.post('/', (req,res) =>{
  news_API(function(newsAPI){
    res.render('index',{ title: 'Stock',
      stock: newsAPI.articles[0].author
    });
  }, req.body.stockText);
});
```

Comment: Please don't include your API keys in the question.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks. I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using same route for both type of api.
Route used in app.get is same ("/").
Use different routes for both request

Comment: What if I wanted the stock information to be on the same page as the stock news?

Comment: Then you will have to combine the results of both external calls in your code.  You might look at [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for hints.

Comment: Scott is right, you can use a api where you'll get both results if you want to always get them together.